# What is more dense, Neutron Star material, or Black Hole material?

Tags: black-holes, condensed-matter, astrophysics, neutron-stars, gravitational-collapse

What is the most Dense material in the Universe? Is it Neutron Star Material? I would think that the Singularity in a Black Hole would be the densest material, or the material that exists moments before that material becomes the Singularity since it seems that the Singularity in not a material? So what then is the densest material in the the universe? I will accept both known and theoretical answers.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45850/discussion-on-question-by-brando-what-is-more-dense-neutron-star-material-or-b).